# Tess4J not running in 32-bit JVM

Tags: java, jvm, java-native-interface, jna, tess4j

I am having an issue getting tess4j to work in a 32-bit jvm environment.  Oddly, it works in 64bit, but not 32bit (opposite of the issue others seem to face).

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: The specified module could not be found.
```

I have created a lib folder in the root directory and placed the dll's in it.

```
System.setProperty("jna.library.path","lib/win32-x86");
```

I have also tried to place the dlls in the root directory, with no luck.
I have attempted to run it from a 32bit ide with 32bit jvm, and still no luck.

I would just use the 64bit as is, but I require using another library that will only work in a 32bit environment.

I would appreciate any input on this.

Thanks

Comment: Run with `-Djna.debug_load=true` and JNA will describe where and how it's trying to load your target library.

Comment: Can you try the latest version 1.4 to see if it would help?